# ListContourPlot in V10

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

It seems that I obtain different results when using `ListContourPlot` under V9 and V10.

Using this datafile http://pastebin.com/2p4ew0NJ (modified to use pastebin), this code:

```
ListContourPlot[cm, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 18, 
 ContourStyle -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 13000}, {0, 8}, {0, 0.0007}}]
```

gives this under V9:

[image: contour plot image]

and this under V10:

[image: contour plot image]

Colors aside, `ListContourPlot` behavior under V10 is to always increase the level (or to change the z plot range) when you go above half the horizontal scale (here above `x = 6500`) -- I verified it  with a lot of other data files.

Comment: I remember 4shared not being completely awful, but I couldn't even use it this time.  Too many junk links that try to download adware.  Try putting it on pastebin maybe?

Comment: I apparently can't download it without having a 4shared account or connect though "social media" which I'm not willing to.

Comment: modified to pastebin - did it work?

Comment: I can confirm that there's something wrong here. You can reproduce the problem in just version 10 by comparing the output of `ListDensityPlot[cm, PlotRange -> {{6566, 13000}, All, {0, 0.0007}}]` with `ListDensityPlot[cm[[2251 ;;]], PlotRange -> {0, 0.0007}]` .  These should give the exact same results but they do not.  I thought the issue might be the irregular grid you use, but that isn't the problem.

Comment: Somehow the interpolation algorithm in `ListContourPlot` and `ListDensityPlot` is messing up here.  As a side note, if you are using `ContourStyle->None`, why not just use `ListDensityPlot`?  A workaround to get the correct plot is to build up an interpolation function:  `cmfunc=Interpolation[cm];DensityPlot[cmfunc[x,y],{x,0,13000},{y,0,8.8},PlotRange->{0,.0007},PlotPoints->100]`

Comment: I didnt use ListDensityPlot because I'm always confused by the variety of plotting functions :-) anyway 1) we can confirm it's a bug (I'll find some other dataset where it is more visible...) and 2) please answer the question so that I can accept it, it's a good solution!

Comment: Version 10.3.0 is still giving the same result. Is this a confirmed bug? Should it be tagged as such? Has this been reported to WRI?

Comment: @P.Fonseca yes. It appears sort order is throwing the interpolation off.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that `ListDensityPlot` connects points incorrectly because of the very big ratio of x- and y-scale. So I propose to rescale the data

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2p4ew0NJ", "Table"];
ListDensityPlot[Transpose[Transpose@data/{1000, 1, 1}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 13}, {0, 8}, {0, 0.0007}}]
```

[image]

Then you can rescale back the plot

```
Show[% /. g_GraphicsComplex :> 
   GeometricTransformation[g, ScalingTransform[{1000, 1}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 13000}, {0, 8}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Crazy solution, I like it!

Answer (score 8):

#### Extended comment

***(Update : NOT fixed in v10.3.1)***

Here is a minimal example which shows clearly that the problem is the difference of the axis scales even for equally spaced points. It concerns **`ListDensityPlot`** and **`ListContourPlot`** but also **`ListPlot3D`**(see Edit below)

```
fp[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)
```

This is the function plot:

```
ContourPlot[fp[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Now, we take equally spaced points from the surface

```
n = 20; xyz = Join @@ Table[{x, y, fp[x, y]}, {x, -1., 1., 1./n}, {y, -1, 1., 1./n}];
```

and now let's change the data scale on one axis only and listplot the new scaled data:

```
xyz // GraphicsGrid[{{ListContourPlot@#, ListDensityPlot@#}}] &
```

[image]

```
MapAt[#*10000 &, xyz, {All, 2}] // 
 GraphicsGrid[{{ListContourPlot@#, ListDensityPlot@#}}] &
```

[image]

```
MapAt[#*30000 &, xyz, {All, 2}] // 
 GraphicsGrid[{{ListContourPlot@#, ListDensityPlot@#}}] &
```

[image]

```
MapAt[#*100000 &, xyz, {All, 2}] // 
 GraphicsGrid[{{ListContourPlot@#, ListDensityPlot@#}}] &
```

[image]

**Edit: `ListPlot3D` also**

The problem concerns also `ListPlot3D` in the exact same way (see also this related [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75499/19960)).

For example:

```
MapAt[#*30000 &, xyz, {All, 2}] // ListPlot3D
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I still don't understand the source of this behavior, it definitely seems to be some sort of bug.  Compare

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2p4ew0NJ", "Table"];
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 13000}, {0, 8}, {0, 0.0007}}]
```

[image]

with this workaround:

```
cmfunc = Interpolation[data];
DensityPlot[cmfunc[x, y], {x, 0, 13000}, {y, 0, 8.8}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, .0007}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I am using version 10.2 (Linux)