# PlotRange precision limit?

Tags: plotting, style

I'm trying to plot a set of points with 9 digits precision with a properly range labelling Y-axis, from a previous question I got two possible ways of doing this:

1st: suggested by @Carl Woll Using BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 9} as a option in listplot, but Mathematica just seems to ignore the option:

```
ListPlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.8037709, 10^-10], 20], 
 PlotRange -> {0.80377085, 0.80377095}, 
 BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 9}]
```

[image]

2nd: suggested by @george2079 using this Ticks options:

```
ListPlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.8037709, 10^-10], 20], 
 PlotRange -> {0.80377085, 0.80377095}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, NumberForm[N@#, {12, 9}]} & /@ 
    FindDivisions[{0.80377085, 0.80377095}, 10]}]
```

[image]

Both options work fine if PlotRange has 7 digit precision or less, but don't show good results for 8+ digits range, any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with my `BaseStyle->{PrintPrecision->10}` suggestion in M11 is that [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) ignores the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange) option. So, one can instead use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) afterwards to get the right [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange). In M11:

```
Show[
    ListPlot[
        RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.8037709,10^-10],20],
        BaseStyle->{PrintPrecision->10}
    ],
    PlotRange->{{0,20},{0.8037708995,0.8037709005}}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's bad habit to plot stuff with a large bias and a small variation. The plotting functions get confused. I'd suggest subtracting the mean and plotting things around 0, and then adding the mean again to the ticks.

```
mean = 0.8037709;
std = 10^-7;
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mean, std], 20];
ListPlot[data - mean,
 PlotRange -> {All, {-3 std, 3 std}},
 Ticks -> {Automatic, 
   Table[{y, NumberForm[y + mean, 10]}, {y, FindDivisions[{-3 std, 3 std}, 5]}]
 },
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -3 std}
 ]
```

[image]

Also, the problem you're specifically referring to is probably due to precision issues, i.e. the fact that the precision of the mean is if of the order of the variation, so Mathematica might treat them as the same number. If you use an exact number for the mean you can easily use more digits:

```
mean = 803770945/1000000000;
std = 10^-15;
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mean, std], 20];
ListPlot[data - mean,
 PlotRange -> {All, {-3 std, 3 std}},
 Ticks -> {Automatic, 
   Table[{y, NumberForm[y + N[mean, 100], 17]}, {y, FindDivisions[{-3 std, 3 std}, 5]}]
 },
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -3 std}
]
```

[image]

Comment: I was using RandomVariate just to illustrate the question, my actual data set is comes from a eigenvalues problem. I'm really surprised that it is necessary to go through such a pain just to just plot some points because the have 9 or more digits.

Comment: (a) You can still subtract the mean. (b) numerical accuracy is indeed a pain in the axe

Answer (score 3):

As of V11, it appears that ticks will print with appropriate precision when the plot range is small.  The problem of poorly scaled data may be addressed by rescaling with [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) and [`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html).

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.8037709, 10^-10], 20];
ListPlot[data,
 ScalingFunctions -> {
   Rescale[#, MinMax[data], {0, 1}] &,
   Rescale[#, {0, 1}, MinMax[data]] &},
 PlotRange ->         (* N.B. PlotRangePadding messes things up! So use manual padding *)
    {{1.05, -0.05},
     {-0.05, 1.05}}.MinMax[data]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Odd restriction: The above plot was generated by executing the right after executing

```
SeedRandom[1];
RandomReal[];
```

If I omit `RandomReal[]`, then the ticks of the plot are rounded to three decimal places, no matter what seed I tried.  But if I followed `SeedRandom` with a `Random*` call, the ticks would be rendered as above.

---

*Alternative:* Scale the data and rescale the ticks.  This approach works with `ListPointPlot3D` as well; e.g. it can be used to solve [ListPointPlot3D small and large values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146113/listpointplot3d-small-and-large-values).

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.8037709, 10^-10], 20];
With[{minmax = MinMax[data]},
 ListPlot[
  Rescale[data, minmax, {0.`, 1.`}],
  Ticks -> {Automatic, 
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Rescale[#1, minmax, {0.`, 1.`}] &, 
      Rescale[#1, {0.`, 1.`}, minmax] &}]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the `data` consists of coordinates instead of being a list of values, then one has to process just the last coordinate.  One substitute, for both 2D and 3D data,

```
minmax = MinMax[data[[All, -1]]]

MapAt[Rescale[#1, minmax, {0.`, 1.`}] &, data, {All, -1}]

Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
  Charting`ScaledTicks[{Rescale[#1, minmax, {0.`, 1.`}] &, 
    Rescale[#1, {0.`, 1.`}, minmax] &}]}
```