# PlotRange is not working in ListPlot for specific data

Tags: plotting

I have a data

```
data = {-35595.14434536`, -35595.15251191`, -35595.15203502`, -35595.15144579`, -35595.15129939`, -35595.15149652`, -35595.15142124`, -35595.15142254`, -35595.15145182`};
```

Plot it using

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> MinMax[data]]
```

I got

[image]

The plot range is not right. I can not see the trend of the data, though the trend is tiny. How to fix the plot range?

---

**Edit**

Thank you for Julius's link. The best simple solution I found is in [Carl Woll's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146122/4742) in that link

```
Show[ListPlot[data], PlotRange -> MinMax[data], Frame -> True]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: @Julius Thank you so much. It indeed answer my question

Answer (score 3):

I do not know why. My guess is that the difference between the min and the max is too small and ignored. The difference is `0.00816655`

Here is a workaround meanwhile

```
data={-35595.14434536`,-35595.15251191`,-35595.15203502`,-35595.15144579`,-35595.15129939`,-35595.15149652`,-35595.15142124`,-35595.15142254`,-35595.15145182`};
{min,max} = MinMax[data];
d = Subtract[max,min];
ListLinePlot[data,PlotRange->{Automatic,{min-2*d,max+2*d}},Mesh->All,MeshStyle->Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. It looks fine except that the plot range is not tight enough :)

Answer (score 1):

To see the trend you could use

```
ListPlot[data - Mean[data], 
PlotRange -> {Min[data - Mean[data]] - 10^-1 Min[data - Mean[data]], 
Max[data - Mean[data]] + 10^-1 Max[data - Mean[data]]}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Andreas.  However, if original data is not need, it seems that simple `ListPlot[data - Mean[data], PlotRange -> All]` works already.